# In Warcraft III, is there a fast way to cast spells when multiple unit types are selected?

Tags: warcraft-3

When I select a bunch of units with different types, I can only cast spells available to the currently "highlighted" unit type. So say I have a paladin, a sorceress, 2 priests and a bunch of footmen selected, and I want to dispel some summoned skeletons.

I have to hit <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to highlight the priests, and only then I can <kbd>d</kbd> a few times for dispelling. Then I suddenly want to use the paladin's heal, so I need to <kbd>shift-tab</kbd><kbd>shift-tab</kbd> before casting the heal. Now I want to dispel again but meanwhile my sorceress might have died, so it's only <kbd>tab</kbd> once now, etc...

Now I understand this is much better than individually choosing the units that have to cast, like in previous Blizzard RTSs, but is there a faster way to use these special abilities? And if there isn't, does anyone have any tips for me to speed up things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not much, but you can (and I'm sure some of the WC3 pros do) individually bind each caster group to a separate control group. That way, you can access your sorceress' spells at any time by pressing "3" (assuming any are still alive), your Priests by pressing "2", the rest of your army by pressing "1", etc.

And of course, if I'm remembering correctly, your heroes are automatically mapped to the F1-F4 keys.

Comment: As far as i remmember, this is the only way without any mods or so. Of course a good programmable gaming keyboard helps a lot ;)

Comment: +1 for F1-F4. Without heros, I usually only need to press tab once. (I also usually split my groups into ranged and melee).

Answer (score -1):

Some spells can be set to Auto-Cast by right-clicking the icon, like the Priests's Inner Fire, but that doesn't help much for the cases you are describing.

I don't know of a faster way to cast spells with a single selection. What I often do is keep several Ctrl-groups for my army and the different casters I care about.  I also use the F-keys for my heroes.

StarCraft 2 is set up in the same way as far as I can tell.  I suspect Blizzard wants casting with subgroups to be part of the skill separating good players from great players, so there aren't shortcuts.  But hey, at least it's better than how it was done in Warcraft II!

Answer (score -1):

I'm failing to understand why you feel pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle through the different unit types in your selection is slow or a hassle.  That's the fastest method that exists.  You just need to [learn to move your fingers faster](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmYhX8fjmo8).